# Swift AVAudioEngine - How to mute local mic

Tags: ios, swift, streaming

I'm using `AVAudioEngine` to get local mic input and then broadcast it. I want to stop getting local mic input when mute button is tapped.

I tried three things:

1. `audioEngine.inputNode.isVoiceProcessingInputMuted = true` - It did not work.
2. `audioEngine.stop()` - Actually it works but causes other problems: I'm using [HaishinKit](https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift) to stream screen-recording + mic-input + other device audio. Stopping the audioEngine causes small lag on viewer side.
3. Mute using `HaishinKit.RTMPStream`: `rtmpStream.audioSettings[.muted] = true` - It works but mutes entire audio. I want to mute only local mic not other device audio.

//

```
private func startTappingMicrophone() {
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: inputFormat) { [weak self] buffer, _ in
          guard let self = self else { return }
          self.conversionQueue.async {
            if let cmSampleBuffer = self.configureSampleBuffer(pcmBuffer: buffer) {
              self.delegate?.recievedRecordedFrame(cmSampleBuffer)
            }
          }
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try? audioEngine.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, it may help to simply not send buffers to the delegate.

But what will work either way is to zero the buffer:

```
if let floatChannelData = buffer.floatChannelData {
    for c in 0..<Int(buffer.format.channelCount) {
        memset(floatChannelData[c], 0, MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Int(buffer.frameLength))
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work but I want to mute only mic not other device audio.

Comment: @LevanKaranadze In my case `audioEngine.inputNode` only produces mic audio, is it different in your case? What other audio comes though?

Comment: In configureSampleBuffer I combine mic input with other device audio. I have to modify this func I guess. I'm doing it according to this git: https://gist.github.com/aibo-cora/c57d1a4125e145e586ecb61ebecff47c

Answer (score 0):

`isVoiceProcessingInputMuted` as the documents say, is related to EchoCancellation. Apple calls AEC "Voice Processing". It is not related to turning on or off the mic's input.

I am not aware of any direct API to mute the microphone.

So to mute the local mic, you need to use the `AVAudioMixerNode`, specifically the `outputVolume` property, see its [doc here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiomixernode/1390244-outputvolume)

Here are the steps to mute it(or adjust the input's volume)

1. Define a mixer node:

   /// mixer node used to adjust the input buffer's volume
   private var inputMixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()
2. Attach your mixer node to your audio engine.

   avAudioEngine.attach(inputMixerNode)
3. Connect the input node to the inputMixerNode

   let input = avAudioEngine.inputNode

   avAudioEngine.connect(input, to: inputMixerNode, format: voiceIOFormat)
4. Set the input volume, it's a float value between 0.0 and 1.0

   inputMixerNode.outputVolume = inputVolume
5. Get the adjusted audio buffer from the inputMixerNode instead of the inputNode.

   inputMixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 256, format: voiceIOFormat) { buffer, when in

   // if inputVolume is set to 0, the buffer is silenced here.
   }